# Find sum of a string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have an excel sheet containing following data pattern.

```
|date           |expenses           |total |

| 01/03/2014    |50 + 100 +10 + 50  |210   |
```

ie date, expenses and total are heading and others are the corresponding data. In this sheet I need to calculate the sum of 'expenses' column, that I need display in 'total' column. Is there is any formula like `=sum(B2)`.

Comment: Do you have only `+` sign in `expenses` column or `-` is also possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple UDF:

```
Function eval(expr As String)
    eval = Evaluate(expr)
End Function
```

and call it like this: `=eval(B2)`.

Note, that length of the `expr` must be less than or equal to 255 characters.

[image]